# Login failed for user 'Administrator'.error 18456

Tags: sql, sql-server, websphere

im trying to conect the sql server via webspher and i'm getting this error  **Login failed for user 'Administrator'.18456**
i have change the server authentication to SQL server and windows authentication restarted it and im still getting this error
i'v checked the user properties and it seems OK
thank you

Comment: Where is the code you used?

Comment: auto connect via websphere

Comment: try this Go to SQL server properties by Right click -> Properties.

then  Enable SQL server authentication mode.

then - Restart the SQL server.

Comment: it was like that and did not work and then i change to sql windows  authentication

Comment: this is the error im getting:  with the following exception: java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'Administrator'. ClientConnectionId:137499f0-9a2e-427d-b4ab-4001bbe097b7 DSRA0010E: SQL State = S0001, Error Code = 18,456.

Comment: Check this page [Resolving connection errors between WebSphere Application Server and SQL Server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1011_supauth/1011_supauth.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login failed for user (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:18456) SQL Server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760919/login-failed-for-user-microsoft-sql-server-error18456-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

Reasons can be many.

One of the reason for me was, azure sql server was disabled because of exceeding free credit.

changed subscription from 'free trail' to 'pay as you go' to enable sql server to be 'active'.

[Azure notification image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKJOD.jpg)